Python unittest.mock patch fail with F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert
A minimal working example is available at https://github.com/rgaiacs/django-mwe-magicmock.
When using Django, I use Model.clean() to validate the form submitted by the user. During the validation, some fields might be updated based on the response of a HTTP request. I want to test the Model.clean() using Python's unittest and mocking the HTTP request.
My app/models.py is
import logging

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

from .aid import GitHosting

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Resource(models.Model):
    code_repository = models.URLField(
        help_text="Link to the repository where the un-compiled, human readable code and related code is located."
    )
    version = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        # Git hash contains 40 characters
        max_length=50,
        default="HEAD",
        help_text="The version of the resource in the format of a Git commit ID or Git tag.",
    )

    def clean(self):
        git_host = GitHosting()
        self.version = git_host.get_version()

and my app/tests.py is
import logging
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Resource

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@patch("app.models.GitHosting.get_version")
class ResourceViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_add_resource(self, mock_get_version):
        mock_get_version = "5678"

        logger.error("Submitting form ...")

        response = self.client.post(reverse("app:index"), {
            "code_repository": "http://mygit.com/foo/bar"
        })

        resource = Resource.objects.get(id=1)

        self.assertEqual(resource.version, "5678")

When I run python manage.py test, the test fail with
ValueError: Failed to insert expression "<MagicMock name='get_version().resolve_expression()' id='139668720464128'>" on app.Resource.version. F() expressions can only be used to update, not to insert.

How can I fix my test? Thanks!

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

mock_get_version = "5678" just reassigns the variable in function scope. You probably wanted to assign to mock_get_version.return_value instead.

Thanks to STerliakov for the answer in the comments. The error was fixed by providing the return_value attribute. The full code snippet is
import logging
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Resource

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@patch("app.models.GitHosting.get_version")
class ResourceViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_add_resource(self, mock_get_version):
        mock_get_version.return_value = "5678"

        logger.error("Submitting form ...")

        response = self.client.post(reverse("app:index"), {
            "code_repository": "http://mygit.com/foo/bar"
        })

        resource = Resource.objects.get(id=1)

        self.assertEqual(resource.version, "5678")

